# Base class of non polymorphic derived classes

Tags: c++

I have the following class definitions:

```
class BaseHandle { /* Lots of things */ };
class VertexHandle : public BaseHandle {
    /* Only static members and non-virtual functions, default dtor */ };
class EdgeHandle : public BaseHandle { /* Dito */ };
class FaceHandle : public BaseHandle { /* Dito */ };
```

All classes have no virtual functions or bases.
The derived classes only derive from `BaseHandle` and do not add any non-static members, nor non-default dtors.

I want to save `Vertex-`, `Edge-` and `FaceHandles` in the same vector:

```
std::vector<BaseHandle*> handles;
```

But it doesn't work, if I retrieve the `BaseHandle` object and want to `dynamic_cast` them to the derived object it fails, because the classes are not polymorphic (that's my explanation perhaps I'm wrong).

How could I achieve a common vector of `BaseHandles`? I should mention, that I can't change the class defintions because they are part of a third party library.

Comment: For polymorphic classes to work, you need at least *one* virtual function: The destructor.

Comment: dynamic_cast is only for polymorphic classes. http://www.codingunit.com/cplusplus-tutorial-polymorphism-and-abstract-base-class

Comment: Perhaps there is a solution to my problem if I use a combination of `typeid` and `static_cast`?

Comment: You could create your own, parallel class hierarchy and add each of those types as a member.

Comment: There is **the** solution to your problem. Use virtual functions. A combination of `typeid` and `static_cast` belongs to the problems domain rather than the solutions domain. You are reinventing the old tired `class BaseHandle { int TYPE; ... }; switch (TYPE) { ...` idiom, which is known to be a huge mess.

Comment: Do any derived classes have additional members, respectivly more base-classes than just `BaseHandle`? Do any of them have user-defined dtors?

Comment: It is generally a sign of a poor design if you have to `dynamic_cast` something before you can use it. I question whether these objects belong in the same `vector`.

Comment: @Deduplicator No other base classes and no user defined destructors. The `VertexHandle` class for example is very simple: `struct VertexHandle : public BaseHandle { explicit VertexHandle(int _idx=-1) : BaseHandle(_idx) {} };`

Comment: Well, in that case look at what I answered. Also added your infor to the question.

Comment: @ChrisDrew I want to put all handles in a spatial data structure. So I can ask, which vertices, edges and faces are within a bounding box. The query result of the data structure are `BaseHandles`. Through casting the `BaseHandle` I would know if it is a Vertex, Edge or Face.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following on from a comment by Kerrek. You could "create your own, parallel class hierarchy and add each of those types as a member". For example:

```
class MyBaseHandle {
 public:
  virtual ~MyBaseHandle(){}
  virtual Box getBoundingBox() const = 0;
};

class MyEdgeHandle : public MyBaseHandle {
  std::unique_ptr<EdgeHandle> handle_;
 public:
  MyHandle(std::unique_ptr<EdgeHandle> handle) : handle_(std::move(handle)) {}
  Box getBoundingBox() const override;
};
```

Then you can `dynamic_cast` if you want to. But I would try and avoid using `dynamic_cast` at all. Add `virtual` methods in your parallel class hierarchy that do what you need. For example I've added a `virtual getBoundingBox` function to the base class that you can then specialize for your particular kinds of handle:

```
Box MyEdgeHandle::getBoundingBox() const {

  // Get data from EdgeHandle
  auto v1 = handle_->getVertex1();
  auto v2 = handle_->getVertex2();

  // create box from edge data...

  return box;
}
```

<kbd>[Live demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/4cNRWJwjlfMSqmZp)</kbd>

Answer (score 7):

You need to have a virtual destructor in your parent class for it to be used polymorphically

```
class BaseHandle 
{
  public:
    virtual ~BaseHandle();

  ...

};
```

That's because `dynamic_cast` works with the RTTI (RunTime Type Information) which is only available if your class has at least one virtual member function

And this will also prevent resource leaks, otherwise only the parent class part of your instance would be destroyed

---

### Workaround

You can use an `std::vector` of [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr), not only will you avoid memory leaks by not having to call `new` and `delete` by hand but that smart pointer also has a magic property (it stores the deleter to call on destruction based on the way it was constructed) that solves your problem:

```
int main()
{
  std::vector<std::shared_ptr<BaseHandle>>      shared_vec;

  shared_vec.push_back(std::make_shared<VertexHandle>());

} // At the end of scope all destructors are called correctly
```

If you don't have access to c++11 you could use [`boost::shared_ptr`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm)

Comment: I should mention, that I can't change the class defintions because they are part of a third party library.

Comment: @TerenceChill Then these classes were not designed to be used with polymorphisme :) Only hacks and workarounds will works

Comment: @TerenceChill I've added a not so horrible workaround

Comment: Any virtual function or base would suffice for using it polymorphically, a virtual dtor is only neccessary for deleting it polymorphically. Though if one has any virtual members or bases, making the dtor virtual too is just common sense...

Comment: I thought that base class has to be polymorphic. Are you sure it is enough to make the derived class polymorphic?

Answer (score 3):

You could store

```
struct thing
{
    enum Type { vertex, edge, face };
    Type type;
    union
    {
        VertexHandle * vh;
        EdgeHandle * eh;
        FaceHandle * fh;
    };
};
```

but it's basically a mess ... are you sure you want to do this?  It looks like you are storing multiple types in a single array despite the fact that there is no way to use them polymorphically, so is there actually a good reason to have only one array, and not three?

Comment: I want to put all handles in a spatial data structure. So I can ask, which vertices, edges and faces are within a bounding box. The query result of the data structure are `BaseHandles`. Through casting the `BaseHandle` I would know if it is a Vertex, Edge or Face. A solution would be to have three spatial data structures, but that's ugly.

Comment: Fair enough.  Unfortunately, without polymorphism, everything you do here is going to be ugly, and I think three separate arrays is perhaps the least ugly.

Answer (score 1):

If all classes derived from `BaseHandle` only use single-inheritance from `BaseHandle` (plus maybe inheritance from empty classes with trivial dtor, which are subject to empty-baseclass-optimization) and don't add anything but non-`virtual` functions and `static` members, and all derived classes use the default dtor or equivalent, you can just `static_cast` to the target.

Though be aware that there is no way to know which of the derived classes, if any, it actually was.

Comment: How could I `static_cast` a `BaseHandle` if I don't know to which derived class the `BaseHandle` points to? No virtual functions means no rtti, so I can't use `typeid` and then casting, right?

Comment: Right. You just have to know, from the `BaseHandle`s members, out-of-band knowledge or whatever. If it matters, and it might not.